# How to configure 'Copy file' and 'Move file' operations in File System Task?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, filesystems

Looking at the [MSDN File System Task Editor (General Page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms183711%28SQL.90%29.aspx) article, it is not clear to me what should be supplied for the source and target values.

It says *"When moving a file, do not include a file name in the directory path that you provide as the destination."* for *move file*, but not for *copy file*.

I would've thought that I could supply

```
SourceVariable = User::MyFileName     
DestinationVariable = User::MyDestinationFolder
```

I'm not having any joy with either move or copy file. The MyFileName var should be set during a `ForEach` container using `*.ext`, but from looking in the watch window, it appears to be set to `filename.ext` and not `c:\source\filename.ext`.

In an earlier part of the package, I'm using the same logic to open and read the files and it's working fine. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had failed to notice the radio buttons on the foreach container, specifically I did not have 'fully qualified' set.

I still don't understand why the 'file opening' part of my package is working perfectly, given that it does not appear to use the path.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by the "file opening" part of your package?  Do you mean where you actually create a connection to the file for processing in a data flow?

Comment: I meant I already have a part in the package where it loops through a bunch of different .ext files, puts the contents into a db, then does some other processing. At the end, I want to move all the files to a 'processed' folder. So I copied the foreach container (keeping everything as is), deleted the contents and put a filesys task in there and was surprised that it didn't work until I selected the 'full path name' in the foreach. I don't understand how the other 'non full path name' has ever worked but it does.